# Working with millions of rows in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a trivial task of iterating over an set of values and performing some kind of operations on each of them, after which sorting that array by its highest value:

```
new_arr = []

@array.each do |val|
  new_arr << calc_operation(val)
end

new_arr.sort!
```

This is a breeze when done on a small-to-medium set of values, but what if I need to crunch a million of them? Specifically,

1. How to speed up the iteration process
2. How to sort data without blowing up the memory usage

I understand there's no trivial solution, so a link to the appropriate article/concept guide would work.

Comment: This needs more information. Where is the data coming from? CSV files, a database etc? If the latter, are you sure your operation can not be performed inside the database? How long does your task take now? How long would you like it to take? Do you really need to sort all the records, or retrieve the top X?

Comment: Thanks. There's no database, I am purely referring to Ruby as a language. The data is currently coming from a CSV file. I am investigating what techniques can be used to speed the iteration up.

Comment: You say that there is no database but does that mean that there *cannot* be a database? This is what databases are for.

Comment: @muistooshort if the database is in place how would that make the iteration faster?

Comment: Some databases are designed specifically for large-scale "map-reduce" type problems, which is roughly what you have here.

Comment: @tadman would love to read about it if you could provide a direction!

Comment: Some of it depends on what exactly `calc_operation` is doing. If you can push that down to the database then you can let the chosen database do all the work (including the sorting). The devil is, of course, in the details though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution in this situation would be parallelizing computations. You are sorting answers at the end, so I assume you don't care about saving order of results, so no need in synchronizing parallel computations.
You could split execution with [`parallel` gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel).

Also, to speed up single computation, you might consider using JRuby.

Regarding memory consumption: I've just tried allocating one million of elements and sorting them. The consumed only 1-2 seconds and 25Mb of memory. 162Mb for ten millions. No big deal. Here is the code:

```
# add 1 at the end to avoid outputting the array to console
ary = (1..1_000_000).map { rand }; 1
ary.sort; 1
```

UPD. You mentioned you get the data from CSV file. You could use `CSV.foreach` to avoid loading whole file into memory.